# Joomla 3.4.1 - after upgrade URL's with article ID's at the end display the article content

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.4

We upgraded 6 Joomla installs with no issues, however we have one that is exhibiting an odd behavior.

Say I have an article ID of 909. If I end the URL with a valid article id it will display the content of that article.  It should go to a 404 page.

```
domain.com/909/                    <-- Display article id 909
domain.com/about/900/              <-- Display article id 900
domain.com/contact-us/855/         <-- Display article id 855
domain.com/contact-us/blah-blah/   <-- Display 404 page
```

All these URLS will resolve and display the content when it should go to a 404 page.  I figured maybe there was a bad router somewhere but I literally replaced the core files with a fresh install.  I'm still getting the behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think they should go to a 404 page? This is similar to a question the other day with numbers in the urls.  Unless you have a menu link to those numbers the router is going to guess that they are really an id number. Why/in what context are you generating such urls?

Comment: Out of the many Joomla installs I'm working on, I only upgraded 6.  This is the first one I ran into this issue with.  The other Joomla installs that have not been updated do NOT exhibit this behavior.  If you are using SEF's and ModRewrites, where else would a url thats not mapped within Joomla go if not a 404 page?

Comment: No that's not how it works. You can make up any text you want, what matters is the number.  The text is just a kind of sugar. That's why I want to know what  is generating such urls, for example are they coming from a drill down?

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  The url's are not being generated by the system.  The menu system is working fine.  I ran into this by randomly trying some url's after the update to make sure it would go to a 404 page.  When it showed me an article instead of a 404 page, thats when I started digging further.

Comment: Right ... people sometimes get into a duplicate content panic because you can use arbitrary names, but as long as there are no links to those arbitrary names there are no duplicate links for Google to spider.

Answer (score 0):

edit com_content/router.php with this code completly. your isue wil be OK. Do not forget to re owerright after new joomla update.

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Build the route for the com_content component
 *
 * @return  array  An array of URL arguments
 * @return  array  The URL arguments to use to assemble the subsequent URL.
 * @since    1.5
 */
function ContentBuildRoute(&$query)
{
 $segments = array();

 // get a menu item based on Itemid or currently active
 $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $menu = $app->getMenu();
 $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
 //$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 0);//اصلی
 $advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 1);//تغییر
 // we need a menu item.  Either the one specified in the query, or the current active one if none specified
 if (empty($query['Itemid']))
 {
  $menuItem = $menu->getActive();
  $menuItemGiven = false;
 }
 else
 {
  $menuItem = $menu->getItem($query['Itemid']);
  $menuItemGiven = true;
 }

 // check again
 if ($menuItemGiven && isset($menuItem) && $menuItem->component != 'com_content')
 {
  $menuItemGiven = false;
  unset($query['Itemid']);
 }

 if (isset($query['view']))
 {
  $view = $query['view'];
 }
 else
 {
  // we need to have a view in the query or it is an invalid URL
  return $segments;
 }

 // are we dealing with an article or category that is attached to a menu item?
 if (($menuItem instanceof stdClass) && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view'] && isset($query['id']) && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])
 {
  unset($query['view']);

  if (isset($query['catid']))
  {
   unset($query['catid']);
  }

  if (isset($query['layout']))
  {
   unset($query['layout']);
  }

  unset($query['id']);

  return $segments;
 }

 if ($view == 'category' || $view == 'article')
 {
  if (!$menuItemGiven)
  {
   $segments[] = $view;
  }

  unset($query['view']);

  if ($view == 'article')
  {
   if (isset($query['id']) && isset($query['catid']) && $query['catid'])
   {
    $catid = $query['catid'];
    // Make sure we have the id and the alias
    if (strpos($query['id'], ':') === false)
    {
     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $dbQuery = $db->getQuery(true)
      ->select('alias')
      ->from('#__content')
      ->where('id=' . (int) $query['id']);
     $db->setQuery($dbQuery);
     $alias = $db->loadResult();
     $query['id'] = $query['id'] . ':' . $alias;
    }
   }
   else
   {
    // we should have these two set for this view.  If we don't, it is an error
    return $segments;
   }
  }
  else
  {
   if (isset($query['id']))
   {
    $catid = $query['id'];
   }
   else
   {
    // we should have id set for this view.  If we don't, it is an error
    return $segments;
   }
  }

  if ($menuItemGiven && isset($menuItem->query['id']))
  {
   $mCatid = $menuItem->query['id'];
  }
  else
  {
   $mCatid = 0;
  }

  $categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
  $category = $categories->get($catid);

  if (!$category)
  {
   // we couldn't find the category we were given.  Bail.
   return $segments;
  }

  $path = array_reverse($category->getPath());

  $array = array();

  foreach ($path as $id)
  {
   if ((int) $id == (int) $mCatid)
   {
    break;
   }

   list($tmp, $id) = explode(':', $id, 2);

   $array[] = $id;
  }

  $array = array_reverse($array);

  if (!$advanced && count($array))
  {
   $array[0] = (int) $catid . ':' . $array[0];
  }

  $segments = array_merge($segments, $array);

  if ($view == 'article')
  {
   if ($advanced)
   {
    list($tmp, $id) = explode(':', $query['id'], 2);
   }
   else
   {
    $id = $query['id'];
   }
   $segments[] = $id;
  }
  unset($query['id']);
  unset($query['catid']);
 }

 if ($view == 'archive')
 {
  if (!$menuItemGiven)
  {
   $segments[] = $view;
   unset($query['view']);
  }

  if (isset($query['year']))
  {
   if ($menuItemGiven)
   {
    $segments[] = $query['year'];
    unset($query['year']);
   }
  }

  if (isset($query['year']) && isset($query['month']))
  {
   if ($menuItemGiven)
   {
    $segments[] = $query['month'];
    unset($query['month']);
   }
  }
 }

 if ($view == 'featured')
 {
  if (!$menuItemGiven)
  {
   $segments[] = $view;
  }

  unset($query['view']);
 }

 // if the layout is specified and it is the same as the layout in the menu item, we
 // unset it so it doesn't go into the query string.
 if (isset($query['layout']))
 {
  if ($menuItemGiven && isset($menuItem->query['layout']))
  {
   if ($query['layout'] == $menuItem->query['layout'])
   {
    unset($query['layout']);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   if ($query['layout'] == 'default')
   {
    unset($query['layout']);
   }
  }
 }

 return $segments;
}

/**
 * Parse the segments of a URL.
 *
 * @return  array  The segments of the URL to parse.
 *
 * @return  array  The URL attributes to be used by the application.
 * @since    1.5
 */
function ContentParseRoute($segments)
{
 $vars = array();

 //Get the active menu item.
 $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $menu = $app->getMenu();
 $item = $menu->getActive();
 $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
 //$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 0);//اصلی 
 $advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 1);//تغییر کرد
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();

 // Count route segments
 $count = count($segments);

 // Standard routing for articles.  If we don't pick up an Itemid then we get the view from the segments
 // the first segment is the view and the last segment is the id of the article or category.
 if (!isset($item))
 {
  $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
  $vars['id'] = $segments[$count - 1];

  return $vars;
 }

 // if there is only one segment, then it points to either an article or a category
 // we test it first to see if it is a category.  If the id and alias match a category
 // then we assume it is a category.  If they don't we assume it is an article
 if ($count == 1)
 {
  // we check to see if an alias is given.  If not, we assume it is an article

/*
//این تیکه کامنت شد  
  if (strpos($segments[0], ':') === false)
  {
   $vars['view'] = 'article';
   $vars['id'] = (int) $segments[0];
   return $vars;
  }
 */
  list($id, $alias) = explode(':', $segments[0], 2);

  // first we check if it is a category
  $category = JCategories::getInstance('Content')->get($id);

  if ($category && $category->alias == $alias)
  {
   $vars['view'] = 'category';
   $vars['id'] = $id;

   return $vars;
  }
  else
  {
   $query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('alias', 'catid')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int) $id);
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $article = $db->loadObject();

   if ($article)
   {
    if ($article->alias == $alias)
    {
     $vars['view'] = 'article';
     $vars['catid'] = (int) $article->catid;
     $vars['id'] = (int) $id;

     return $vars;
    }
   }
  }
 }

 // if there was more than one segment, then we can determine where the URL points to
 // because the first segment will have the target category id prepended to it.  If the
 // last segment has a number prepended, it is an article, otherwise, it is a category.
 if (!$advanced)
 {
  $cat_id = (int) $segments[0];

  $article_id = (int) $segments[$count - 1];

  if ($article_id > 0)
  {
   $vars['view'] = 'article';
   $vars['catid'] = $cat_id;
   $vars['id'] = $article_id;
  }
  else
  {
   $vars['view'] = 'category';
   $vars['id'] = $cat_id;
  }

  return $vars;
 }

 // we get the category id from the menu item and search from there
 $id = $item->query['id'];
 $category = JCategories::getInstance('Content')->get($id);

 if (!$category)
 {
  JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ERROR_PARENT_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
  return $vars;
 }

 $categories = $category->getChildren();
 $vars['catid'] = $id;
 $vars['id'] = $id;
 $found = 0;

 foreach ($segments as $segment)
 {
  $segment = str_replace(':', '-', $segment);

  foreach ($categories as $category)
  {
   if ($category->alias == $segment)
   {
    $vars['id'] = $category->id;
    $vars['catid'] = $category->id;
    $vars['view'] = 'category';
    $categories = $category->getChildren();
    $found = 1;
    break;
   }
  }

  if ($found == 0)
  {
   if ($advanced)
   {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
     ->select($db->quoteName('id'))
     ->from('#__content')
     ->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' = ' . (int) $vars['catid'])
     ->where($db->quoteName('alias') . ' = ' . $db->quote($segment));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $cid = $db->loadResult();
   }
   else
   {
    $cid = $segment;
   }

   $vars['id'] = $cid;

   if ($item->query['view'] == 'archive' && $count != 1)
   {
    $vars['year'] = $count >= 2 ? $segments[$count - 2] : null;
    $vars['month'] = $segments[$count - 1];
    $vars['view'] = 'archive';
   }
   else
   {
    $vars['view'] = 'article';
   }
  }

  $found = 0;
 }

 return $vars;
}
```